# Xcode 6 iOS app enterprise distribution via URL

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, ipa

We have an iOS app, which stopped installing with the following error:

> "Unable to Download App [name] could not be installed at this time"

when trying to install on any iOS version 9 devices.

I used `Xcode 6` to rebuild .ipa file and used plist and html files from the old build, but we still get the same error. Also I do not know how to recreate plist using `Xcode 6`.

Any help would be great

Comment: Can you rebuild with XCode 7? If it is failing on iOS9 devices, it is likely an issue with the SDK, and you would need to publish with the latest version of XCode ...

Comment: Are you able to plug the device you are trying to install on into your Mac? If so open up the device window in xcode and look at the console output for your device when you try to download the app. It will give more info on the failure reason (it's usually down to not hosting on https, code signing issues, invalid deployment targets (i.e iPhone, not iPad or incompatible versions)). If you can't figure out the error message for yourself then update your questions and somebody might be able to help further

Comment: XCode 7 requires updating code as there are a lot of changes from xcode 6, so I'd like to avoid this option.

Comment: Checking the output helped. The problem was caused by the old distribution profile, which had to be recreated after the membership was renewed. Also Xcode displayed a warning that i'm accessing a newer device, the app installed OK with the new profile. I even kept  the old plist and html files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by creating a new distribution profile. After searching more on this, I found the following text on page 86 of in the Apple's iOS Deployment Reference (https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1685/en_US/ios_deployment_reference.pdf)

> If your distribution certificate expires, the app won’t launch. Your
>   distribution certificate is valid for three years from when it was
>   issued, or until your Enterprise Developer Program membership expires,
>   whichever comes first. To keep your certificate from expiring, be sure
>   to renew your membership before it expires.
>
> You can have two distribution certificates active at the same time,
>   with each independent from the other. The second certificate provides
>   an overlapping period in which you can update your apps before the
>   first certificate expires. When you request your second

Looks like the app has to be repackaged with a new distribution profile each year after renewing the membership.

Also this App still worked on iOS 9 when I used Xcode 6 to repackage it using new profile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you properly export the ipa from Xcode, according to the [Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH33-SW6). Make sure to 
select *“All compatible device variants”*. You can also select to create a new plist manifest at the export.

The server has to serve the html website over TLS/SSL. Is your certificate valid and trusted by iOS? Your server has support everything that [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) requires, i.e. TLS 1.2 with forward secrecy.

> Requirements for Connecting Using ATS
>   With ATS fully enabled, your app’s HTTP connections must use HTTPS and must satisfy the following security requirements:
>
> The server certificate must meet at least one of the following trust requirements:
>   Issued by a certificate authority (CA) whose root certificate is incorporated into the operating system
>   Issued by a trusted root CA and installed by the user or a system administrator
>   The negotiated Transport Layer Security version must be TLS 1.2
>   The negotiated TLS connection cipher suite must support forward secrecy (FS) and be one of the following:
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   The leaf server certificate must be signed with one of the following types of keys:
>   Rivest-Shamir-Adleman (RSA) key with a length of at least 2048 bits
>   Elliptic-Curve Cryptography (ECC) key with a size of at least 256 bits
>   In addition, the leaf server certificate hashing algorithm must be Secure Hash Algorithm 2 (SHA-2) with a digest length of at least 256 (that is, SHA-256 or greater).

Answer (score 0):

if you update the ios with the latest ios 9.2 the issue will be solved.

Thanks.